# Assistance writing a Prolog rule

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

Given that I have entered the  following facts into the factbase. Each sidedish has two ingredients:

```
maindish(thanksgiving, turkey). 
sidedish(thanksgiving,pie). 
ingredient(pie,spice).
ingredient(pie,sugar).
```

I have written the following rule to return the dishes for a given holiday:

```
meal(Holiday, [F1,F2]) :- maindish(Holiday,F1), sidedish(Holiday,F2).

?- meal(thanksgiving, Foods).
```

I am trying to write a rule  called `ingredientList` that will identify the type of ingredients needed for each holiday. By associating the dishes and ingredients for each given holiday.

Comment: Please get informed how this site works by reading [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

```
ingredientlist(Holiday, Ingredients) :-
   setof(Ingredient,
          Dishes^Dish^ ( meal(Holiday,Dishes),
                         member(Dish, Dishes),
                         ingredient(Dish, Ingredient) ),
         Ingredients).
```